# Video Upload Speed very slow in iPhone Application using Amazon S3

Tags: ios, iphone, video, amazon-s3

Friends,

I've an application developed which is mainly based upon uploading the live recorded videos like Instagram does. I'm facing a major challenge with it's uploading speed. I'm using amazon S3 for uploading videos.

Any solution anyone can suggest ?

Looking ahead for the response.

Comment: increase you internet speed then that wont take much time

Comment: can i know how you are uploading your video to s3?@BrahmaSys

Comment: @Nitin - Internet speed is good. Tried in 8MBPS, 4MBPS and simultaneously I have checked other apps too Vine , Snap and Instagram. Their speed is very good.

Comment: @Madhu We are using Amazon iOS SDK to upload videos.

Comment: We are using amazon s3 to upload videos. I just want to know the mechanism for uploading the video(base64 or multipart) so that i can help you.@Vinay

Comment: @Madhu - Thanks for helping out. We are using multipart form data to post using presigned url to amazon. 

Also, I'd like to know if bucket region have any impact on uploading speed. We are uploading videos from India to Ireland region. 

Thanks again. Will look forward to your suggestions.